# How does my discord bot react to messages outside the / command

Tags: python, discord, nextcord

Let's take a quiz as an example, the user makes the command "/quiz rules" to start a quiz about the rules.
How do I then make the bot accept the user's next messages as answers?

Python - nextcord

```
@client.slash_command(guild_ids=[testing_id])
async def quiz(interaction: Interaction,
               value: str = SlashOption(
                   name="value",
                   choices=["rules"]
               )):
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you'll want to add a client event listener and do something when the `on_message` event fires.

- [Nextcord event reference](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#event-reference)
- [`on_message`](https://docs.nextcord.dev/en/stable/api.html#nextcord.on_message) event

```py
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    # do something with the message here
```

So for your quiz example; you'd have to keep track of when a quiz has started, which channel it's in, and which user initiated it (provided you only want a particular user answering) and then parse the message to see if it's an answer to the question it was asked. But using `on_message` is what I would do.

You could also use the [`wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Client.wait_for) method to wait for a message from a particular user as well.